# Function exported and imported, no errors, but getting '... is not exported from ...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've never seen this before.

I try to export a function and import it in another file. When I attempt an import, my autoimport tool finds it and imports it. Autocompletion is even there when I reference to it. There are no errors showing in code, but I get a console error when compiling that says the function is not exported...

Exported from queries...

[image]

The import statement

[image]

Note that I've also tried  without success

`import { getAllRoles } from '../graphql/queries'`

Now where I actually use the imported function...

[image]

As you can see, no syntax / import error highlighted, and when I save and compile...

[image]

On top of all that, note that the queries file containing the exported function is auto-generated by Amplify codegen from an AppSync API, so I can't see why they'd mess it up.

I'm very confused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two files with the same name in the same folder, one js and one ts. It tried to import the .js file for some reason.